# Rest Callout to External Resource, 401 Unauth Error, Cannot Set Api Key

Tags: rest-api, authorization

I am having issues giving an API key to an external url for a rest callout.

`req.setHeader` is where I attempt to do so. How should I structure this? I only get 401 unauth errors.

I am trying to authenticate using the CampaignMonitor API via an API Key.

https://www.campaignmonitor.com/api/getting-started/#grab-a-wrapper

```
public class HttpCallOut {

    public string getJSONResponse(String url) {

        Http h = new Http();

        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();

        req.setEndpoint(url);
        req.setMethod('GET');

        // Set Api Key
        req.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer a5p4dkey382apikey3382nns21jsskeyi29');

        HttpResponse res = h.send(req);

        system.debug(res);
        return res.getBody();

    } 
}
```

Comment: You said you are using the API Key method, but you are clearly using the OAuth access token method. Refer 'Authenticating with an API key' section in the link you provided.

Comment: @Avinash I do not think I can do a curl from apex?

Comment: Then you will have to follow the OAuth process...Create a connected app, generate access token by calling https://api.createsend.com/oauth/token and use it in the setHeader.

Answer (score 0):

cURL is not supported by Apex so you will need to follow the OAuth flow.  Please refer to the docs here [REST API Docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/intro_curl.htm) and recheck your information for the API for [Campaign Monitor](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/api/getting-started/#grab-a-wrapper) and set your application up to use OAuth appropriately

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to campaign monitor
2. the API key from the Account Settings page when logged into your Campaign Monitor account.
3. Below is the code for cURL and Apex that will help you get started. Note that this uses BASIC authentication, not oAuth. The header construction is the major difference here.

your curl will look like this `curl -u "YOURAPIKEY:x" https://api.createsend.com/api/v3.2/clients.json?pretty=true`

Here is the code to call from apex

```
String username = 'YOURAPIKEY';

String password = 'x';  
Blob headerValue = Blob.valueOf(username + ':' + password);
String authorizationHeader = 'BASIC ' + EncodingUtil.base64Encode(headerValue);


Http h = new Http();
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
req.setEndpoint('https://api.createsend.com/api/v3.2/clients.json'); //update this for your actual query
req.setMethod('GET');
req.setHeader('Authorization', authorizationHeader);
req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');


HttpResponse res = h.send(req);
System.debug(res);
System.debug(res.getBody());
System.debug(res.getStatusCode());
```